# how to use awk/cut to get column data which has space

Tags: sed, awk, cut

I have data in below format:

```
 16 SQL*Plus                            vilconv1                  dox-conv2
 16 TOAD background query session       Disha                     WORKGROUP\AD
```

now I want to get data by column, I am using below command

```
awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

but since column 2 has spaces it;s giving me below output :

```
16 SQL*Plus      
  16 TOAD
```

whereas what I want is:

```
16 SQL*Plus  
   16 TOAD background query session
```

Comment: Does your data fit a fixed-width format?

Comment: Is each row delimited by tabs, or are those literal tabs? Also, is it only the second column that has spaces? Are there spaces in any other column?

Comment: Use `cut -c -40`

Comment: And maybe sed 's/ *$//' to remove trailing spaces, if that matters

Comment: @Costas that's by far the best method if there's no tabs, why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If the columns are separated by tabs you can specify the tab character as the field separator.  This will prevent the default behavior of awk to treat spaces as separate columns.

```
cat <data file> | awk -F"\t" '{print $1, $2}'

root@ubuntu32:/tmp# cat testtext | awk -F"\t" '{print $1, $2}'
16 SQL*Plus
16 TOAD background query session
```

Comment: No need to flog the feline; Awk can be passed a filename for input...

Answer (score 1):

Liked @Costas suggestion, and another option is:

```
gawk '
  {
    f1=substr($0,2,2)
    f2=substr($0,4,36)
    gsub(/ *$/, "", f2)
    print f1 " " f2
  }
'
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me a lot to find a way to extract part of string of specific column

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this could involve `unexpand`. The description for it and the `expand` utility can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html#tag_20_41):

- The `unexpand` utility shall copy files or standard input to standard output, converting `<blank>` characters at the beginning of each line into the maximum number of `<tab>` characters followed by the minimum number of `<space>` characters needed to fill the same column positions originally filled by the translated `<blank>` characters. By default, tabstops shall be set at every eighth column position. Each `<backspace>` shall be copied to the output, and shall cause the column position count for tab calculations to be decremented; the count shall never be decremented to a value less than one.

You'd probably want the `-a` switch though.

- `-a` -
  In addition to translating `<blank>` characters at the beginning of each line, translate all sequences of two or more `<blank>` characters immediately preceding a tab stop to the maximum number of `<tab>` characters followed by the minimum number of `<space>` characters needed to fill the same column positions originally filled by the translated `<blank>` characters.

It's a simple utility for converting many spaces in sequence to tabs instead. In that way you could...

```
unexpand -a <<\IN | cut -f1
 16 SQL*Plus                            vilconv1                  dox-conv2
 16 TOAD background query session       Disha                     WORKGROUP\AD
IN
```

...which prints...

```
 16 SQL*Plus
 16 TOAD background query session
```

I just use `cut` there, but if you wanted to you could use `awk` or anything else really. I only suggest it because you almost definitely already have it installed, it is very simple to use, and very fast. It solves the space problem by swapping delimiters - and it does so very easily.

I also use a here-document just to show how it works, but you'd probably want to do instead...

```
unexpand -a <infile | filter program
```